# Add "Create" option to the StackExchange OpenID login page

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange-openid

After reading the blog entry announcing the StackExchange OpenID provider, I was anxious to add a StackExchange login to my account for redundancy. I went to update my account and clicked on the new StackExchange OpenID button. I didn't see an option to create a new login, only to use an existing one.

It took a lot of digging to figure out that I needed to go to http://openid.stackexchange.com; a simple "**Create New Account**" button would have been very helpful.

Comment: +1, however, shouldn't that rather read: "... anxious to make my current openid redundant"? ;-)

Comment: I second this, in fact, I only found out what to do via this post. A handy "create account" button/link would be a great idea.

Comment: I third this - I'd like to move off my other OpenID provider since I only use it on StackExchange sites anyway. Could figure this out until I found this post too :)